# CSS - how to set up header images as use eg. Facebook?

Tags: html, css, image, resolution

I wonder how to set up the header image on my website. The basic problem - let's say I am on my laptop - the width resolution is around 1280px. I have a header image that has the width like 2000px.

What I would like to achieve is, that on my laptop would be this header-image resized to 1280px and on my LCD monitor (the width resolution like ±1900px) would be displayed the iamge with 1900px - I mean, in both cases fit to display.

My current CSS setup is the `width: 100%;` -> this caused that the 2000px width image will be cropped on my laptop - are displayed just 2/3 of the image.

Is there any way to set the image always  to fit to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for the following css:

```
.headerimage{
    background-image: url(...);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

this resizes the background-image to correspond with the container-size.

Comment: What do you mean, by "for CSS2"? if you are looking for browser support, see this: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries):

Browser window width less than 1280px

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
   #myHeader {
      width: 50% // resize it to 50% when the browser screen is **LESS** than 1280px
   }
}
```

Browser window width larger than 1280px but smaller than 2000px:

```
@media (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
   #myHeader {
      width: 75% // resize image at 75% when the browser screen is **BETWEEN** 1280px and 2000px    
   }
}
```

Browser window width larger than 2000px:

```
@media (min-width: 2000px) {
  #myHeader {
      width: 100% // resize header to 100% when screen is **LARGER** than 2000px
  }
}
```

And so.. customize the breakpoints and widths as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using javascript:

```
<script>
// first set viewport width and viewport height to vpw and vph
var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],vpw=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth,vph=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;

d.getElementById( "your_image_id" ).style.width( vpw+"px" );
</script>
```